# Retrieving multiple records through has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I am working on a Ruby on Rails 4 application which allows users to check off movies that they have seen. I have a page that shows a list of movies, captured through a `Film` model. Also, I have a `Nomination` model that captures each Oscar nomination along with `Person` and `Song` models that can also have nominations and belong to a `Film`.

On the page that lists the movies, I also want to show all of the categories that a film is nominated for. I know that I can simply access all of the film nominations via `@film.nominations` since I have created this has_many association, but this doesn't capture any person or song nominations that belong to that certain movie.

**Is there a way to show all of the nominations for a given movie, regardless of whether the nomination is for a film, person, or song?**

Here are the models that I currently have:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  # DB columns: name, display_order

  has_many :nominations
end


class Nomination < ActiveRecord::Base
  # DB columns: category_id, nominee_id, nominee_type

  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :nominee, polymorphic: true

  validates :category, presence: true
  validates :nominee, presence: true
end


class Film < ActiveRecord::Base
  # DB columns: name, image_url
  has_many :nominations, as: :nominee
  has_many :film_views
  has_many :people
  has_many :songs
end


class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  # DB columns: name, film_id
  belongs_to :film
  has_many :nominations, as: :nominee
end


class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  # DB columns: name, film_id
  belongs_to :film
  has_many :nominations, as: :nominee
end
```

Comment: is movie and film are two different models

Comment: No, they are the same model. I just use the terms interchangeably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since in all cases Nomination of any person or song is in someway related with a movie.
it makes sense that Nomination should have a movie id; with this your problem is already solved. NB a main reason for that is because a person should belong to one or more Film.

**Anyway**
If you want to get all nominations given a film you can use this code

```
def all_nominations
  Nominations.where(nominee_type: 'Person', nominee_id: self.people.map(&:id)).or(nominee_type: 'Song', nominee_id: self.songs.map(&:id)).or(nominee_type: 'Film', nominee_id: self.id)
end
```

Comment: You solution worked for me, with some slight modification:

self.nominations + Nomination.where(nominee_type: 'Person', nominee_id: self.people.map(&:id)) + Nomination.where(nominee_type: 'Song', nominee_id: self.songs.map(&:id))